# Backbone.js back button not loading proper view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my Backbone application, I'm trying to figure out why when I click the back button on a page, the URL changes appropriately but the actual browser display does not.

Here's one flow:

1. Go to application: elections/
2. Starting page: elections/#profile/manage/:id/
3. Page clicked to: elections/#profile/manage/:id/personalInfo/
4. Back button clicked. Should end up displaying elections/#profile/manage/:id/

However when the back button is clicked, the page display doesn't change, just the URL.

I'm not sure what's causing this nor how to get around this. I've read some things about options to the Backbone.history.start() command, but whenever I add anything to it, nothing displays.

Not really sure how to go about fixing this problem. Can someone point me in the right direction? (I can expand the code samples if need be, I just thought this might be easier to read)

**elections/app.js - called from elections/index.html**

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/lib',

    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        tpl: '../tpl',
        bootstrap: 'bootstrap/js/',

    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
    }
});

require([
    'jquery', 
    'backbone', 
    'app/router',
], function ($, Backbone, Router) {
    var router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start({pushState:true});
});
```

**elections/js/router.js - instantiated in app.js**

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var $           = require('jquery'),
        Backbone    = require('backbone'),
        WindowView   = require('app/views/Window'),

        breadcrumbs = {"Home": ""},
        $body = "",
        $content = "",

    return Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            ''                                                : 'home',

            'profile/login(/)'                                : 'candidateProfileLogin',
            'profile/manage(/)'                               : 'candidateProfileLogin',
            'profile/manage/:id(/)'                           : 'candidateProfileHome',
            'profile/manage/:id/:section(/)'                  : 'candidateProfileSection',
        },

        initialize: function () {
            require([], function () {
                $body = $('body');
                windowView = new WindowView ({el: $body}).render();
                $content = $("#content", windowView .el);
            });
        },

        candidateProfileHome: function (id) {
            require(["app/views/Candidate", "app/models/candidate"], function (CandidateView, models) {
                var candidate = new models.Candidate({id: id});
                console.log('router: candidateProfileHome');
                candidate.fetch({
                    success: function (data, response) {
                        var view = new CandidateView({model: data, el: $content});
                        view.render();
                    },
                    error: function (data, response) {
                        var view = new CandidateView({model: data, el: $content});
                        view.render();
                    }
                });

                breadcrumbs['Profile Home'] = Backbone.history.fragment;
                windowView.addBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs);
                windowView.selectMenuItem('candidate-menu');
            });
        },

        candidateProfileSection: function (id, section) {
            require(["app/views/Candidate", "app/models/candidate"], function (CandidateView, models) {
                var sectionNames = {
                    'questionnaire': 'Questionnaire',
                    'endorsements' : 'Endorsements',
                    'photo'        : 'Photo',
                };
                var sectionName = sectionNames[section];

                var candidate = new models.Candidate({id: id});
                candidate.fetch({
                    success: function (data, response) {
                        var view = new CandidateView({model: data, el: $content});
                        view.render(section);
                    },
                    error: function (data, response) {
                        //Output the data to the console. Let the template take care of the error pages
                        console.log(data);
                        var view = new CandidateView({model: data, el: $content});
                        view.render(section);
                    }
                });

                breadcrumbs['Profile Home'] = "profile/manage/" + id + "/";
                breadcrumbs[sectionName] = Backbone.history.fragment;
                windowView.addBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs);
                windowView.selectMenuItem('candidate-menu');
            });
        },

        candidateProfileQuestionnaire: function (id, page) {
            require(["app/views/Candidate", "app/models/candidate"], function (CandidateView, models) {
                var pageNames = {
                    'personalInfo': 'Personal Information',
                    'essay'       : 'Biography & Essay',
                    'survey'      : 'Survey Questions',
                    'endorsements': 'Endorsements',
                    'photo'       : 'Photo'
                };
                var pageName = "Questionnaire: " + pageNames[page];

                var candidate = new models.Candidate({password: id});
                candidate.fetch({
                    success: function (data, response) {
                        console.log('success');
                        var view = new CandidateView({model: data, el: $content});
                        view.render(page);
                    },
                    error: function (data, response) {
                        //Output the data to the console. Let the template take care of the error pages
                        console.log('error');
                        console.log(data);
                        var view = new CandidateView({model: data, el: $content});
                        view.render(page);
                    }
                });

                breadcrumbs['Profile Home'] = "profile/manage/" + id + "/";
                breadcrumbs[pageName] = Backbone.history.fragment;
                windowView.addBreadcrumbs(breadcrumbs);
                windowView.selectMenuItem('candidate-menu');
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems the urls still have hashes yet you are using push state; your `elections/#profile` route seems odd to me - am I missing something? I would assume `elections/profile` route to be correct.

Comment: Sorry, elections is the folder everything is in on the machine. I should have clarified that in the beginning. :)

Comment: I'm really looking at the '#' in `/#profile` is that the beginning of a hash fragment? You shouldn't be using hash fragments with push state enabled. Also is your server side code is coded properly to handle push state?

Comment: I have no idea? I don't even know what push state does, I'm just trying different things to try and fix this back-button issue. If it wasn't already obvious, I don't really know what I'm doing. I've been using backbone for...2 weeks now? I'm having to learn as I go.

Comment: ok first thing; don't use push state.

Comment: can u also provide your functions executed by each route. have you put logging in them to see if your routes are getting fired?

Comment: Hi @clintronx, I've updated the code for my router. I do have a log in candidateProfileHome. It triggers when you first land on the page (like you would expect), and then again when you click the back button to return to that page.

Comment: refactor suggestion: since your fetch `success` and `error` callbacks are the same move them into a single `fetch.always()` block. Can you put a break point in these callbacks to ensure your `$content`, `data`, and `view.render()` return what you expect.

Comment: Oh jeez, I just figured it out. It didn't have anything to do with either file, but how I was declaring my templates in the View. I have a template that loads by default outside of the Backbone.View.extend() block, (the one for #profile/manage/:id), and then in the render function it checks what page I'm on, and if it's a different path, it selects a different template. If I move the template declaration for the default template into the render block with everything else, it works just fine.

Thank you for all the help @clintronx, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to specifically configure Backbone's router to handle browsers history state or events, it's built in. The issue lies somewhere else...in your case it was the view, rendering the template.

Answer (score 0):

we have two solutions

Backbone.Router.navigate("url", {trigger: true});

or

Backbone.history.back();

Comment: Ok, but how does that help me override default functionality of the browser's back button?